# How to save arrayList<Custom Object> in local storage android?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-external-storage

I have an app that fetches uri and name of the images and returns `arrayList` of `ArrayList<ImageModel>`. Where Image Model consists `uri` and `name` two variables and `Getter` and `Setter` for each.

```
try {
            FileOutputStream outputStreamWriter = getContext().openFileOutput("config.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStreamWriter);
            oos.writeObject(arrayList);
            oos.close();
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
```

When I try to save `arrayList` Using above methid it throws `java.io.NotSerializableException: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri` Exception. But, my `ImageModel` implements`Serializable`.

```
 try {
            FileInputStream fis = getContext().openFileInput("config.txt");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Object object = ois.readObject();
            return object;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
```

Because File is not written it makes this read method return null. So, I need suitable solution to save that `arrayList` to local storage and retrive it. Further I am going to load images uri by `arrayList.get()` method. So, I suppose `ArrayList` is must.

Comment: Uri is not serializable so you must to use a String type in your ImageModel, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot save objects to storage directly, you have to serialize them and then store this serialized data into storage. You have to read the serialized data, then deserialize it to get back your object. [More on serialization](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)

In your code, `oos.writeObject()` requires that passed object must be serializable, but your ImageModel is not because of having a member of type Uri.

Possible workaround: Modify your ImageModel class to be serializable. And keep your storage read/write logic unchanged.

**ImageModel class**

```
public class ImageModel implements Serializable {
    private String uriString;
    private String name;

    public ImageModel(Uri uri, String name) {
        this.uriString = uri.toString();
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public Uri getUri() {
        return Uri.parse(uriString);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setUri(Uri uri) {
        this.uriString = uri.toString();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

There are also other options for serialization (ie. Json) and you can also use them.

Comment: I did that. I also mentioned in question that my `ImageModel` class implements `Serializable`

Comment: Not just implement Serializable, did you make ImageModel like my answer? I mean, Uri member as String?

Comment: Yeah I tried that. For some reason at first it was not working. Not sure why but, When I created new class `Image` and copy pasted the code inside that It worked,I had to replace `ImageModel` to `Image` every where but, In the end It worked.

Comment: The reason, Uri is not serializable directly, so oos.writeObject() cannot. Here we just store the Uri in ImageModel as String so that ImageModel becomes serializable, that's it.

Comment: Yes. I did the same and then I parsed the String back to uri when I needed it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey, I ran into another problem. Do you think you can help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68312983/cannot-find-the-created-txt-file-in-android-local-storage